# How to implement a Search Box Process in my HTML Website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, search

I am looking for a means of implementing a "Search" routine/page that I can apply to my site that is purely a HTML website only.

I have provided a Search box for the user but unsure what the next step is, i.e. can I insert php to perform the Search of my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/). It has the functionality of a Google Search, it is customizable, and it is really easy to set up. All you need is a site and a Google Account.

Here's how you get started:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/docs/start.html